How can I improve React Leaflet performance when rapidly updating a marker position?
I'm working on a page which reads GPX files (a series of lat/lon GPS points) and plots the route using React Leaflet as well as showing an elevation profile using react-chartjs-2.
When hovering over the elevation profile, the nearest data/GPS point is displayed on the map via a marker like so:

Unfortunately this causes a re-render every time, and results in laggy/stuttering performance when there are more than a few hundred GPS points (most of the GPX files I'm dealing with contain thousands).
I'm aware of hooks such as useMemo and useCallback but I'm not sure if/how they can be applied to my setup.
Any advice would be appreciated.

I attempted to make an interactive code sample earlier but it proved quite difficult due to the large amount of code as well as the various plugin imports/requirements, so here's a rough outline of how it works:
function App() {
    // Array containing several thousand GPS point objects
    const gpsPoints = [
        {
            lat: 36.05287,
            lon: -112.08383,
            ele: 2193.501708984375,
            time: '2020-03-21T14:19:02.000Z',
        },
        ...
    ];

    // The current index into the gpsPoints array, set when hovering over the elevation profile
    const [pointIndex, setPointIndex] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <RouteMap gpsPoints={gpsPoints} pointIndex={pointIndex} />
            <HeightMap gpsPoints={gpsPoints} setPointIndex={setPointIndex} />
        </>
    );
}

// Using React Leaflet library
function RouteMap({ gpsPoints, pointIndex }) {
    const start = gpsPoints[0];
    const position = gpsPoints[pointIndex];

    return (
        <MapContainer center={start}>
            <TileLayer url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
            <Polyline positions={gpsPoints} />
            <Marker position={position} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}

// Using react-chartjs-2 library
function HeightMap({ gpsPoints, setPointIndex }) {
    const options = { ... };
    const data = { ... };
    
    // Chart.js plugin API - calling setPointIndex(...) here is what causes performance to suffer
    const plugins = [
        {
            id: 'show-marker',
            afterDraw: (chart) => {
                if (chart.tooltip?._active?.length) {
                    setPointIndex(chart.tooltip._active[0].index);
                } else {
                    setPointIndex(0);
                }
            },
        },
    ];
    
    return <Line options={options} data={data} plugins={plugins} />;
}

